# IndexError: index 89 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 89

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am getting this error but I dont understand how to solve it, Can anyone please help. I am trying to run a pre-implemented project on my own text dataset. I am using CUB 200-2011 bird dataset which had initially 11788 birds images and author model has been trained and tested with 11788 images . but for some reason many images were missing when I downloaded the dataset so total I have only 2200 images and 1629 images for training. (you can see in the error as well Model is reading 11788 images filenames from somewhere but found only 1629)

After running the training file:

```
python3 bird_01_pretrain.py

Namespace(audio_model='Davenet', batch_size=128, cfg_file='cfg/Pretrain/bird_train.yml', data_path='data/birds', exp_dir='', gpu_id=0, image_model='VGG16', img_size=256, lr=0.001, lr_decay=50, manualSeed=200, margin=1.0, momentum=0.9, n_epochs=120, n_print_steps=2, optim='adam', pretrained_image_model=False, resume=True, rnn_type='GRU', save_root='outputs/pre_train/birds', simtype='MISA', tasks='extraction', weight_decay=0.001)

Total filenames: 11788 001.Black_footed_Albatross/Black_Footed_Albatross_0046_18.jpg

Load filenames from: data/birds/train/filenames.pickle (1629)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "bird_01_pretrain.py", line 145, in <module>

dataset = SpeechDataset(cfg.DATA_DIR, 'train',

File "/opt/app/dataset/datasets_pre.py", line 358, in __init__

seq_labels[unique_id[i]-1]=i

IndexError: index 89 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 89
```

Code:

```
# cacluate the sequence label for the whole dataset
    if cfg.DATASET_NAME == 'birds' 
        if self.split =='train':
            unique_id = np.unique(self.class_id)
            seq_labels = np.zeros(cfg.DATASET_ALL_CLSS_NUM)
            for i in range(cfg.DATASET_TRAIN_CLSS_NUM):
                seq_labels[unique_id[i]-1]=i
                
            
            self.labels = seq_labels[np.array(self.class_id)-1]
```

I am getting an error at this line: seq_labels[unique_id[i]-1]=i

datasets_pre.py file has around 400 lines of codes and calling many other modules as well. I would be happy to share if anyone wants to see whole code and other files as well but for now I am trying to give exact piece of code which is causing the error.

Please help me :)

I can also provide the author open github repo link if anyone wants to look into deeper.

Comment: Print the values of `unique_id` and `seq_labels` right before the loop to find out which one is giving you the `IndexError`.

Comment: I did and it gave me this results:                                                                              
Output: Total filenames:  11788 001.Black_footed_Albatross/Black_Footed_Albatross_0046_18.jpg
Load filenames from: data/birds/train/filenames.pickle (1629)

Comment: unique ID: [  2   3   7  10  11  13  15  17  19  20  21  24  25  26  27  30  32  39
  40  41  42  44  45  47  52  54  56  60  63  64  68  69  87  89  90  94
 109 110 111 116 118 127 129 132 133 134 136 137 139 140 141 142 143 146
 148 151 153 155 157 158 159 160 161 162 164 167 168 170 171 172 173 174
 175 176 177 179 181 182 184 188 189 190 191 192 194 195 198 199 200]

Comment: Seq label: [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. ]

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12492/4236200340.py in <module>
----> 1 SpeechDataset('data/birds')
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12492/4234694649.py in __init__(self, data_dir, split, img_size, transform, target_transform)
    329    print("Seq label:", seq_labels)
    330    for i in range(cfg.DATASET_TRAIN_CLSS_NUM):
--> 331                     seq_labels[unique_id[i]-1]=i
    332 
    333 

IndexError: index 89 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 89

Comment: sorry, I meant `len(unique_id)` and `len(seq_labels)`. Although I just checked this real quick with the values you provided and `unique_id` has 89 items and `seq_labels` has 121; so you're getting this exception cause `range(cfg.DATASET_TRAIN_CLSS_NUM)` is returning a range that goes beyond `unique_id`'s 88 limit.

Comment: Thank you so much :) With your help I was able to solve the issue